# how to manage if - else here..

Tags: php, mysql

I know my code is bad and unsafe and everything but I just want it to overall work before I start making changes.

So i am making a little basic shop, and I want it to check the user to see if he has the right amount of money, and if he does, subtract the amount of money the item costs and give him the item, if he does not have the right amount, I want it not to subtract any and not give him the item and echo that he cannot afford the item. I tried to do it with no success so I deleted most of the code and was hoping to get a little help here.

This is what I still have.
if I take out the if statement it will minus the the money and add the item, but I need the restrictions on it. I am very new to all of this so any help is appreciated :)

```
$sql23 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."')";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

   echo $row['money'];
   if (isset($_POST['pokeball'])) {
      if ($row['money'] >= 2000) {
          echo "You have bought a pokeball!" ;
          mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money=money-2000 WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'") 
            or die(mysql_error());

          mysql_query("UPDATE users SET pokeball=pokeball+1 WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")
            or die(mysql_error());  
       } else {
          echo "You can't afford a pokeball!";

       }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've pointed out your code is not great, however in answer to your actual question/problem. 
As the whole thing hinges on one if statement, everything that is suppose to happen should be inside that if statement.

```
 $sql23 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."')";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo $row['money'];
if (isset($_POST['pokeball'])) {
    if ($row['money'] >= 2000) {
        echo "You have bought a pokeball!" ;
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money=money-2000 WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'") 
            or die(mysql_error());

        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET pokeball=pokeball+1 WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")
            or die(mysql_error());  
    } else {
        echo "You can't afford a pokeball!";

}
}
```

}

Also note mysql_query is depreciated and should be replaced with mysqli_query : 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Thanks for the help, its almost working XD I think I have the if statement wrong from where its checking to see if you have the right amount of money because it always comesback as can't afford it :/

Comment: sorry to bother you more but, I still can't get it to work I edited my origonal post with what im using now, and it still always says that I can't afford the pokeball no matter how much money I have, I made it echo out $row['money']

Comment: when I echo it out it gives me 11514 and that is the amount of money I have on my user in the database.

Comment: but when I do print_($result) it gives me Resource id #33

Comment: I added what it prints out in my question.

Comment: You need to put { after the while and close it , I'll amend your example code on my post

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$playermoney = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'") or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST['pokeball'])) {
    if ($row['money'] >= 2000) {
        echo "You have bought a pokeball!" ;
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money=money-2000,pokeball=pokeball+1 WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'") 
            or die(mysql_error());

    } else {
        echo "You can't afford a pokeball!";
}
?>
```

Comment: $playermoney = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";  is missing the mysql_query function